# Laravel Model is not getting any value from table

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

why is my model doesnt give me any data, before its working fine when i try to take the data like `$standart->name`, but now it give me `null`. i dont know what's happening.

tried to die dump and here's what i got:

```
    public function show(Standart $standart)
    {
        dd($standart);

        return view('admin.datas.standart', compact('standart'));
    }
```

```
App\Models\Standart {#1249 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
```

standart model:

```
class Standart extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::get('/standarts/{standarts}', [App\Http\Controllers\StandartController::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: can you show Standart  model code

Comment: already edited my post

Comment: Can you also add the routes code that executes this function?

Comment: yes, already added

Comment: I think your variable name needs to match your route param, and `$standart` doesn't match `{standarts}` (s vs no s). It should probably be `{standart}`

Comment: oh my godddd, what a silly mistake. thank you so muchh

Answer (score 0):

You have to use resource route like,
In web.php file

use App\Http\Controllers\StandartController;

Route::resource('standarts', StandartController::class);

And after this too you are getting table name null then you have to mention table name in model like,

protected $table = 'your_table_name_here';

Answer (score -1):

Your route param binding and function's param binding has different name.

```php
Route::get('/standarts/{standarts}', [App\Http\Controllers\StandartController::class, 'show']);
```

Change **standarts** to **standart** and it should work.